# Setting breakpoints in VS code using Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

Running into ruby version clash when trying to start the rails debugger inside of VS Code. Sorry if this is a stupid question.. I'm normally a Js guy, very new to Rails

Getting this error :

```
      rake (>= 0.8.1)
WARN: Clearing out unresolved specs.
Please report a bug if this causes problems.
Uncaught exception: Your Ruby version is 2.3.7, but your Gemfile specified 2.3.1
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:495:in `validate_ruby!'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:470:in `validate_runtime!'
.
.
.
```

When I type `ruby --version` in my console, I get `ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-darwin17]`

Comment: Do you have correctly specified ruby in your Gemfile like: `ruby "2.3.7"`? Or does it says `2.3.1` ?

Comment: yeah it's specified as 2.3.1

Comment: try setting this value to `ruby "2.3.7"` in your Gemfile

Comment: I specifically need ruby v2.3.1

Comment: I should clarify: I can run the app normally, I'm just getting this error in the VS Code debugger environment

Answer (score 0):

Had this same issue.
Restarting the computer worked for me.

The vscode debugger console environment doesn't seem to update until a complete computer restart happens. Might be a bug or intentional.